# Gnome Tweak Tools: dropdown does not work

Tags: gnome-tweak-tool

I've just installed gnome-tweak-tool on Ubuntu 17.10 and some themes to customize my desktop. 
In the tab Appearance > Themes > Applications there is a dropdown menu to choose another theme, but when I click (for a long time) on it, there is no dropdown.
It's strange because the dropdowns just below (cursor, icons) works.

I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-tweak-tool && sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

But the problem is still here. How to fix it ?

Comment: Have you installed any other themes to choose among?

Comment: Yes I did using git. I solved the problem using the mouse wheel, but the dropdown is still not there.